# How can I print the type of a PyObject in an error message for an embedded Python script?

Tags: python, c++

My C++ code has this check in it:

```
if (1 != PyString_Check( key ))
```

and I'd like to get a "char*" of the type that it actually is in order to provide a more useful error message. Using the C API for Python, how would I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
PyTypeObject* type = key->ob_type;
const char* p = type->tp_name;
std::cout << "My type is " << p << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 9):

As of Python 2.6, there is [a macro, `Py_TYPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.Py_TYPE), which should be used to access the type object of a `PythonObject`. You can then fetch the [`tp_name` field](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_name) which contains the fully-qualified name of the type. This means that the type of an object `obj` can be fetched as a C-string with:

```cpp
const char* p = Py_TYPE(obj)->tp_name;
```

Comment: As of Python 3.10, `Py_TYPE` will be a function, not a macro but the above example will continue to work in exactly the same way.